# Using a Flux instead of a for loop, any benefits?

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am trying to get my head around reactive programming so I would like to ask if there is any benefit to using a Flux here:

```
override fun notifyObserversOnMessage(message: Message) {
        Flux.fromStream(observers.stream())
                .map { observer -> Mono.just(observer.reactOnMessage(message)) }
                .subscribe()        
    }
```

instead of:

```
override fun notifyObserversOnMessage(message: Message) {
        for (observer in observers) {
            observer.reactOnMessage(message)
        }       
    }
```

Does it depend on the work each observer is doing and if that is IO or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

If it is reasonable to process `observers` sequentially, there is no benefit to using Flux here and

```
override fun notifyObserversOnMessage(message: Message) {
    observers.forEach { observer ->
        observer.reactOnMessage(message)
    }
}
```

or simply

```
override fun notifyObserversOnMessage(message: Message) {
    observers.forEach { it.reactOnMessage(message) }
}
```

is fine.

For naïve parallelism,

```
override fun notifyObserversOnMessage(message: Message) {
    observers.parallelStream().forEach { it.reactOnMessage(message) }
}
```

can be used, but at this point it's more likely you'll have additional requirements such as worker pools or timeouts. In that case the expressiveness of Reactor is useful.

Comment: If every observer writes the message to a DB, will it be done asynchronously with a Flux or the loop is going to run still sequentially?

Comment: @Orestis As you've written it, it is sequential. One way to get parallelism is something like `observers.toFlux().flatMap { observer -> Mono.fromCallable { observer.reactOnMessage(message) }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()) }.subscribe()`.